# Using jQuery to restructure elements displayed via nested tables

Tags: jquery, dom

I know there are a thousand questions like this, but after hours and hours of reading and fiddling, I still can't do what I'm trying to do (which is likely to be the wrong thing to do in the first place).

I have a site which generates page code like this (cleaned up and simplified for clarity):

```
<div id="sectionFiles">
    <table class="LISTNAMES" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1305">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"> 

                    <table class="LISTNAMES" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="16" align="LEFT" valign="top"><img src="webicon?-16+-T+38425053+-C+3842494D" height="16" border="0" width="16"></td>
                                <td align="left" valign="CENTER"> <span id="inwinstr0" class="SMALLFONT">&nbsp; </span> </td>
                                <td align="RIGHT" valign="top"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="112">
                                <td colspan="3" height="112" align="CENTER" valign="TOP"> <a href="Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd"><img id="Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd" src="Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd" alt="Display Larger Preview" height="75" border="0" width="112"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="16">
                                <td colspan="3" height="16" align="CENTER" valign="TOP">Cinema 22 Red 8oz Label.psd </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="24">
                                <td colspan="3" align="CENTER" valign="center"> <a href="getimage?-high+-n+-id+4010787+/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" alt="Download Hi-Res File" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="getimage?-fpo+-n+/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" alt="Download Low-Res File" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="imageinfo?/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" onerror="this.src=&quot;&quot;" alt="Info" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="imageorder?/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" alt="Custom order" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="" onclick="window.openBasket(0); return false;" title="Add to basket"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </td>
                <td align="center"> 

                    <table class="LISTNAMES" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="16" align="LEFT" valign="top"><img src="webicon?-16+-T+38425053+-C+3842494D" height="16" border="0" width="16"></td>
                                <td align="left" valign="CENTER"> <span id="inwinstr1" class="SMALLFONT">&nbsp; </span> </td>
                                <td align="RIGHT" valign="top"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="112">
                                <td colspan="3" height="112" align="CENTER" valign="TOP"> <a href="getimage?-web+-id+4010786+/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd"><img id="previewImg/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd" src="getimage?-small+-id+4010786+/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd" alt="Display Larger Preview" height="75" border="0" width="112"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="16">
                                <td colspan="3" height="16" align="CENTER" valign="TOP">Cinema 25 Red 8 oz Label.psd </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="24">
                                <td colspan="3" align="CENTER" valign="center"> <a href="getimage?-high+-n+-id+4010786+/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" alt="Download Hi-Res File" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="getimage?-fpo+-n+/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" alt="Download Low-Res File" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="imageinfo?/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" onerror="this.src=&quot;&quot;" alt="Info" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="imageorder?/Cinema%2025%20Red%208%20oz%20Label.psd"><img class="button" alt="Custom order" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a> <a href="" onclick="window.openBasket(1); return false;" title="Add to basket"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <option value="-1" selected="">All (53) </option>
</div>
```

Each inner TABLE.LISTNAMES, contained within a TD of the parent TABLE.LISTNAMES, contains all the data I need within it's own TDs. Essentially I'm wanting to eliminate the use of tables completely, wrapping the html contained in the lowest level TDs with class named DIVs (e.g. icon, thumbnail, name, actions) for use in a responsive Bootstrap gallery of tiles.

What I'm attempting to do is:

1. Create an array of the inner tables
2. Loop through that array and strip the TDs inner html
3. Wrap the results of those in the Bootstrap framework

The output framework I'm ultimately looking to achieve for each inner table's data is something like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a><img><##></img></a><!-- Asset thumbnail image and link -->
        <div class="caption">
            <img><##></img><!-- Asset icon -->
            <h3><##></h3><!-- Asset name -->
            <p><##></p><!-- Whatever else-->
            <p><##></p><!-- Asset actions -->
        </div><!-- /.caption -->
    </div><!-- /.thumbnail -->
</div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->
```

or specifically:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd">
            <img id="Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd" src="Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd" alt="Display Larger Preview" height="75" border="0" width="112">
        </a><!-- Asset thumbnail image and link -->
        <div class="caption">
            <img src="webicon?-16+-T+38425053+-C+3842494D" height="16" border="0" width="16"><!-- Asset icon -->
            <h3>Cinema 22 Red 8oz Label.psd</h3><!-- Asset name -->
            <p>...</p><!-- Whatever else-->
            <p>
                <a href="getimage?-high+-n+-id+4010787+/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd">
                    <img class="button" alt="Download Hi-Res File" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a>
                <a href="getimage?-fpo+-n+/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd">
                    <img class="button" alt="Download Low-Res File" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a>
                <a href="imageinfo?/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd">
                    <img class="button" onerror="this.src=&quot;&quot;" alt="Info" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a>
                <a href="imageorder?/Cinema%2022%20Red%208oz%20Label.psd">
                    <img class="button" alt="Custom order" src="" height="16" align="top" border="0" width="16"></a>
                <a href="" onclick="window.openBasket(0); return false;" title="Add to basket"></a>
            </p><!-- Asset actions -->
        </div><!-- /.caption -->
    </div><!-- /.thumbnail -->
</div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->
```

---

**SOLUTION**
After going back to basics and getting a far better understanding of how jQuery works in order to accomplish a task like this... I was able to come up with the following solution. (It surely isn't the most efficient way to do this, but at least I'm getting the results I'm looking for.)

```
// Build key/value object from pre-generated shortdisplay code
var assetTables = $('table.LISTNAMES tbody tr td table').map(function(i, v) {
    var $td =  $('td', this);
    return {
        id: ++i,
        icon: $td.eq(0).html(),
        messageBox: $td.eq(1).html(),
        offline: $td.eq(2).html(),
        preview: $td.eq(3).html(),
        name: $td.eq(4).html(),
        actions: $td.eq(5).html()
    }
}).get();

// Build thumbnail display using object assetTables
for (var i = 0; i < assetTables.length; i++) {
    var myThumbnail = [
        '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 assetFile" id="assetFile'+i+'">',
        '   <div class="thumbnail">',
        '       <div class="assetPreview">'+assetTables[i].preview+'</div>',
        '       <div class="caption">',
        '           <h3 class="assetTitle">'+assetTables[i].name+'</h3>',
        '           <p class="assetInfo">'+assetTables[i].icon+''+assetTables[i].offline+'</p>',
        '           <p class="assetActions">'+assetTables[i].actions+'</p>',
        '           <p class="assetMessages">'+assetTables[i].messageBox+'</p>',
        '       </div>',
        '   </div>',
        '</div>'
    ];
    $('div#sectionAssetDisplay').append(myThumbnail.join(''));
};
```

Comment: You should include your code samples, seeing as that's where the problems lie.

Comment: @J.Titus -- I've added my code attempts...

Comment: `$(this).find('td').html();` should probably be `$(value).find('td').html();` since `value` will contain the HTML code from the previous `.each`.